# Zero-inflated model predicting only a small range of values. I need help

Tags: r, prediction, zero-inflation

I built a ZI model and it is producing predicted values that are from a very small range when compared to the observed values. Plus it does not produce any zeros. See the fitted vs. observed graph below.

[image]

My model structure is given below. My response is a count variable and the predictor is continuous water level measurements (scaled).

```
m.u.meanwl.gu <- zeroinfl(GU ~ MeanWLScaled | MeanWLScaled, data = uluabat_wl_fg, dist = "negbin", link = "logit")
```

I need help to figure out what's wrong and fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are your input variables?  It looks like the non-zero part of the fit doesn't "have much to go on".  What makes you think that zero-inflated captures the behavior of your system well?

Answer (score 3):

If you call `predict.zeroinfl()` without any parameters, it uses the default setting for the `type` parameter, which is `type="response"`. You will then get a prediction for the *mean*, or the *expected* response. This expectation will typically vary much less than your actual observations, will not be integer, and will be larger than zero.

To obtain a probabilistic prediction of the probabilities to observe specific actual count observations, use `type="prob"`. An example:

```
> library(pscl)
> fm_zip <- zeroinfl(art ~ ., data = bioChemists)
> head(predict(fm_zip))
       1        2        3        4        5        6 
2.037956 1.323124 1.308704 1.439982 2.363233 0.854771 
> head(predict(fm_zip,type="prob"))
          0         1         2          3          4           5           6
1 0.2162690 0.1937560 0.2279639 0.17880748 0.10518810 0.049503684 0.019414543
2 0.3626973 0.2429423 0.2058847 0.11631983 0.04928840 0.016708046 0.004719819
3 0.3655549 0.2445794 0.2051107 0.11467420 0.04808441 0.016129943 0.004508999
4 0.3582308 0.2127514 0.2034182 0.12966290 0.06198734 0.023707199 0.007555727
5 0.1071273 0.2125181 0.2559524 0.20550920 0.12375553 0.059619449 0.023934814
6 0.5218005 0.2328010 0.1513963 0.06563783 0.02134296 0.005551943 0.001203522
            7            8            9           10           11           12
1 0.006526345 0.0019196452 5.019025e-04 1.181028e-04 2.526437e-05 4.954139e-06
2 0.001142821 0.0002421248 4.559820e-05 7.728561e-06 1.190849e-06 1.682002e-07
3 0.001080390 0.0002265110 4.221291e-05 7.080172e-06 1.079567e-06 1.508923e-07
4 0.002064075 0.0004933813 1.048304e-04 2.004632e-05 3.484891e-06 5.553353e-07
5 0.008236171 0.0024798688 6.637118e-04 1.598722e-04 3.500850e-05 7.027254e-06
6 0.000223623 0.0000363569 5.254177e-06 6.833844e-07 8.080398e-08 8.758139e-09
            13           14           15           16           17           18
1 8.967384e-07 1.507227e-07 2.364440e-08 3.477356e-09 4.813281e-10 6.292303e-11
2 2.192977e-08 2.654955e-09 2.999969e-10 3.177955e-11 3.168471e-12 2.983515e-13
3 1.946804e-08 2.332345e-09 2.607955e-10 2.733875e-11 2.697294e-12 2.513358e-13
4 8.168817e-08 1.115779e-08 1.422441e-09 1.700050e-10 1.912317e-11 2.031584e-12
5 1.302074e-06 2.240273e-07 3.597518e-08 5.415971e-09 7.673982e-10 1.026932e-10
6 8.762517e-10 8.140690e-11 7.058791e-12 5.738134e-13 4.390178e-14 3.172269e-15
            19
1 7.792861e-12
2 2.661494e-14
3 2.218703e-14
4 2.044694e-13
5 1.301911e-11
6 2.171585e-16
>
```

Look at `?predict.zeroinfl` for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Sir. I understood what you said. However, this function is no longer available in the most recent form of `"pscl"`package. So I simply used the generic `predict()` function with `type ="prob"` command. It gave me a huge object with tons of numbers in it. It basically has probabilities for each possible value I guess. All I want to do is to use a basic predicted vs observed graph to see how well my model is performing and I still can't do it. Is there a way to get this plot by the method you said for either `zeroinfl` or `glmmTMB` objects.

Comment: `predict.zeroinfl()` is available in [`pscl` 1.5.2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pscl/index.html), see p. 60 in [the reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pscl/pscl.pdf). ...

Comment: ... About getting a predicted vs. observed graph: there are different ways of predicting. What you had originally was a plot of predicted expectations. Which does not give an indication of variability. You could extract predicted probabilities, then calculate lower and upper quantiles and plot those. Then you could check whether, e.g., 80% of observations are between the 10% and the 90% quantile prediction.